# Changing how returned output is displayed in Django

Tags: python, django, jinja2

I recently started learning Python/Django as a whole and in an attempt to speed up my learning curve and at the same time do something constructive I've started my own personal project.

I've got the latest Django/Python/Jinja2 installed together with the Python Battle.net API egg.
Currently I'm querying for a "character" and I'm trying to change the output of a returned value, here's the function from my views:

```
def viewCharacter(request, name):
    character = get_object_or_404(Member, name=name)
    info = Character('EU', 'Auchindoun', name, fields=[Character.GUILD])

    ctx = { 'character': character, 'info': info, 'guildname': 'Guild Name' }
    return render_to_response("roster/viewCharacter.html", ctx, request)
```

Now, in my template, I've tried "translating" info.class_ (which returns a numeric value) from it's numeric value to a string (The class name) but I'm always getting error messages about info.class_ not being able to be used in if/for statements/loops or other errors. (Tried comparing it to a two-tuple)

I really can't find a way to do this online, so I've come to the one place that have helped me the most in my learning process.

Any help would be most appreciated!
- Nieeru

Comment: Can you paste your template code here? How do you "translate" the `_class`?

Comment: It's mostly been through trial and error. I don't have the template code anylonger as I've started trying to do this from scratch!

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to use a classname in template, try using [this](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/294/) template filter, or just get it in the view and pass in a context :)

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason you can't add another variable to the context like so:

ctx = { 'character': character, 'info': info, 'class': repr(info.class_), 'guildname': 'Guild Name' }

EDIT: With the additional information you provided, here is my new suggestion.

Change:

```
ctx = { 'name': name, 'character': character, 'info': info, 'class': repr(info.class_), 'guildname': 'Team-Potato' }
```

to:

```
ctx = { 'name': name, 'character': character, 'info': info, 'className': classnameDict[info.class_], 'guildname': 'Team-Potato' }
```

This simply does the class look up in the view. Now add it to your template using

{{ className }}

Comment: Not at all!  I'm open to all suggestions.

Comment: Righty. Take a look at my views
def viewCharacter(request, name):
 character = get_object_or_404(Member, name=name)
 info = Character('EU', 'Auchindoun', name, fields=[Character.GUILD])
 classnameDict = { 1: 'Warrior',2: 'Paladin',3: 'Hunter',4: 'Rogue',5: 'Priest',6: 'Death Knight',7: 'Shaman',8: 'Mage',9: 'Warlock',10: 'Unknown',11: 'Druid', }

 ctx = { 'name': name, 'character': character, 'info': info, 'class': repr(info.class_), 'guildname': 'Team-Potato' }
 return render_to_response("roster/viewCharacter.html", ctx, request)

How would I go about translating info.class from the new dict?

Comment: No translation necessary in the template (that's what `repr` does), just output it using the new variable in your template: `{{ class }}`

Comment: {{ class }} returns exactly the same as info.class_ unfortenally. The ID of the character's class rather than the translated name!

Comment: Let me try and re-explain.  info.class_ returns the ID of a character's class (from World of Warcraft) without any translation to what the class name is. What I want to achieve is a way to point that ID to the actual class name rather than the ID. Say for instance info.class_ returns "5", I want to translate that to "Priest", for instance.  I've created a tupled list with the information in and passing it through the context. I just can't get it to translate.

Comment: Awesome Brad!  I JUST thought of it like that myself.

Comment: Could not have done it without you mate. I submit myself to the dust at your feet.  Thanks again!

Comment: No need to get your face in the dust, but can you vote for my answer? ;)